# How we save the recorded data and replay again using rrweb?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using rrweb with vue.js in which I'm facing a problem which is when I record the data and play it again it's working.
But in which what I want to save the data first and then play the recorded item.
I have data like this:

```
rrweb(){
            let vm = this;
            let stopFn = rrweb.record({
                emit(event) {
                    if (vm.events.length > 200) {
                        vm.count = vm.count + 1;
                        stopFn();
                        vm.play()
                    }
                    // recording
                    vm.events.push(event)
                }
            })
        },
        play(){
            let vm = this;
            if(vm.count==1){
                new rrwebPlayer({
                    target: document.getElementById('replay'), // customizable root element
                    data: {
                        events: vm.events,
                        autoPlay: true,
                    },
                });
                vm.save(vm.events);
            }
            else{
                console.log('else statement');
            }
        },
        save(events) {
            const body = JSON.stringify({ events });
            // console.log(body);
            events = [];
            fetch('deadend/getrrbData', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body,
            });
        }
```

In which firstly I call the rrweb and other functions invoked through this.
But I'm confused about how I can save data at our end and then play again.
Link for your reference.

https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb

https://gitlab.com/lbennett/vue-rrweb

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your endpoint is working fine, unless you put 'deadend/getrrbData' to not reveal your endpoint.
   Reference link for fetch with then callback:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

   2. Also a thing to mention, since rrweb record returns a function that stops recording, I don't know if you were able to play the recorded events because you were calling vm.play after stopping recording events.
   3. Apart from POST url endpoint I really did not find any potential issue with your code, check this post fetch request example

      ```js
      // Example POST method implementation:

      try {
        const data = await postData('http://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // JSON-string from `response.json()` call
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }

      async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
        // Default options are marked with *
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
          mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
          cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
          credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
          referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
          body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        });
        return await response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
      }
      ```

**To replay after sending post request**

you can use the same events that you sent in your body of POST

Good luck!